# Find and replace character in web page

Tags: php, regex

I have a website that has an x in the top corner that has been placed into a file - this website has many is there a quick way to search to find an alone "x" - thats not used in a word?

Comment: Huh? Any sample? Any attempts?

Comment: "an x in the top corner" basically tells us NOTHING. a graphic that looksl ike an X? a literal character 'x'? Some other characters that happen to make a pattern that looks like an X?

Comment: grepity grepity grep grep grep with shell access

Comment: My guess is, someone cut/pasted something, but the `CTRL` key (CTRL-X) probably wasn't fully pressed. Hey, it's happened to me, it could happen to anybody, and that `x` is probably the result of that. Call me crazy, but let's not leave it out of the equation, *as it were.*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep thats what I am guessing it is - http://d.pr/i/zJJq but where haha

Comment: @JessMcKenzie It's probably part of a lightbox element using an image as the `X` to close a box and is in a CSS file somewhere. However knowing the URL to the page itself would be better. Hard to tell from what you've given me to check.

Comment: @JessMcKenzie Any chance for you to put your source code here? It's always better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use developer tools and really need the regex to search through the source file (*and it's an actual text character `x`*), then this (probably inelegant) regex should do it:

```
(\Wx\W)|(^x\W)|(\Wx$)
```

The `\W` means "not a 'word' character".  This may or may not quite work for you depending on what you have in the source file (particularly if you have UTF-8/international characters, I'm not sure how Sublime Text 2 will treat all of that with relation to `\W`).

`^` means "beginning of line".  `$` means "end of line".  An `x` at the start or end of a line, with no other 'word' characters around it would count!

The `( )` are merely logical groupings (can be used as matched references in other cases like replacing text), and the `|` means "or" (so the regex is simultaneously looking for three different patterns, here).  The `x` is just the literal character.

Tests from Sublime Text 2 follow.

Matches:

```
x as
x asdf
asdf x
asdf x asdf
as x
>x
a x<
```

Doesn't match:

```
xas
asdxafd
asdfx
```

You really should make an attempt, too. It often leads to a better understanding of the problem (in this case, understanding regular expressions).

Comment: I have done a file search :) Will try this now

Answer (score 0):

Use firefox/chrome/ie/opera dev tools, right click the 'x', inspect the element. It will lead you to the location in the source.

Comment: I have used this but its not showing http://d.pr/i/zJJq and I cant find the related document

Answer (score 0):

You've used an inspector like FireBug or Chrome Console to try and track it down? If so, find its code and try searching all your files with a tool like [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) for that string.